# Обновление данных

Tags: xcode, coredata, objective-c

Здравствуйте.

Имеются данные в коре дате, нужно реализовать обновление этих данных. Данные в кору дату загружаются при первой установке и первом запуске приложения из сайта. После первых запусков уже не загружаются с Интернета, а грузятся с коры даты.

Как можно реализовать проверку на обновление данных и загрузку новых данных в кору дату?

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняйте последнее время обновления БД или кой-либо другой идентификатор. А при запуске проверяйте, делов-то.

Comment: Я не понимаю: вы не в состоянии сравнить два массива объектов?)) 

Если старые не нужно удалять, так еще проще: достали Б, сравнили, взяли новые объекты, добавили в массив Б, сохранили. Какие тут могут быть трудности?))

Comment: Ну вот как это сделать? Массивы сравниваю на данный момент по коунтам, и если они разные, то оповещает только, что есть новые данные. А вот как добавить эти новые?..

Answer (score 0):

Если данные поступают в отсортированном виде (или их сортонуть в обоих эрреях), то ничто не мешает взять ластиндекс кордатовского массива, и добавлять эелементы с интернет массива, начиная с ластиндекс+1.